# Specify sql expression as column name in a django orm query

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-orm

Look at this query:

```
select 'DEFAULT_STRING' as category from foo
```

Here, we don't really have the column `category` in the table, but we just use a string literal to represent this column value in all rows returned by the query. In place of a string literal, we could have any valid SQL expression above. Is there some way to have this query in the django ORM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A handy way of doing this is to `annotate` with [`RawSQL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#raw-sql-expressions) query expression.

```
from django.db.models.expressions import RawSQL
qset = Foo.objects.annotate(category=RawSQL("select 'DEFAULT_CATEGORY'", ()))
```

Please let me know in the answers if there are better ways of doing this.